# Git in PyCharm using a pre-existing repository

Tags: git, bash, github, version-control, pycharm

So I hadn't realized that PyCharm has its own git functionality.  As of now, I already have a local repository and a remote repository, only they were created with git bash.  The project I'm currently working on is already located in that local repository.  I want to integrate PyCharm to let me work with those repositories.

There's a lot of information on how to create a repository, but I can't seem to follow anything talking about using repositories that already exist.

So the main thing I want is to be able to put my current project in my currently existing local repository - from there, I'd like to be able to push/add to the currently existing remote repository.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick point, it does not matter what interface created the git repo or what ones you use to work with. I often jump between different tools and integrations. It is all git.

As for adding an existing repo go into preferences and got to the project settings group and select Version Control. In that main window you should see a + and - to add and remove integration with git repos. After that you should see a VCS menu on the main window.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Pycharm (2016 - 2017) to add an existing repository to your project, go to File | Settings then seek for Version Control Option in the left pane. in it's view you should see the address of your project and the VCS type (mostly git). if not, click the green "+" button and add your project info. restart Pycharm and you shall see VCS integration options enabled.